# FOSUserbundle access user from other controller

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserbunble, how can access the user object from another controller/form in another bunble?
for example I have a BlogBundle and when I create a new post I need to save the userId in the post table.
for the form I'm using buildForm extending AbstractType.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try `$user = $this->getUser();`

Comment: OK I can access the property using $this->getUser(); or through security.context, but what's the best way to pass it to the form? do I have to inject it in the object or there is a better way?

Comment: You can pass it to the form if you need it there.  Otherwise, it'll be available in the controller after the form is validated.  Once validated I assume you'd do something like `$post->setUser($user);` or get the user id with `$id = $user->getId();`.

Comment: OK it works passing the user object to the setId method, it works but I don't understand how
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $project->setIdUser($user);
....
    public function setIdUser(\Cpj\UserBundle\Entity\User $idUser = null)
    {
        $this->id_user = $idUser;
        return $this;
    }

thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Glad it works for you - it's an example of the usefulness of OOP. If this answer solves your question, please consider accepting it. If you'd like more help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via SecurityContext.
  let's a example ..

```
  namespace YourPackage\UserBundle\Controller;

  use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
  use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
  use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;

 class YourController extends Controller{
 /**
 * Fetch a user object.
 *
 * @Route("/yourRoute", name="your_route")
 * @Method()
 * @Template()
 */
public function yourAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();


    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('your_route'));
}}
```

Comment: Why are you getting the user from the security context and then getting it again using the repository?

Comment: ya u r right , there is no need to get user from repository while already gotten through security contest ., now i have modified my answer ..